# Can someone fix my pause script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

Can someone fix my pause menu script ?(I want it to stop the ball) Here's the link of my project: http://mediafire.com/download/33poh7jalkcvjzh/Jumpy+ball.rar

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class pauseMenu : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GUISkin myskin;

```
private Rect windowRect;
private bool paused = false , waited = true;
private float time = 60f;

private void Start()
{
    windowRect = new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 100, Screen.height / 2 - 100, 200, 200);
}

private void waiting()
{
    waited = true;
}

private void Update()
{
    if (waited)
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.P))
    {
        if (paused)
            paused = false;

        else
            paused = true;

        waited = false;
        Invoke("waiting",0.3f);
    }
    if(!paused)
        if(time>0)
            time -= Time.deltaTime;
}

private void OnGUI()
{
    if (paused)
        windowRect = GUI.Window(0, windowRect, windowFunc, "Pause Menu");
    GUI.Box(new Rect(1, 2, 70, 30), "Time: " + time.ToString("0"));
}

private void windowFunc(int id)
{
    if (GUILayout.Button("Resume"))
    {
        paused = false;
    }
    if (GUILayout.Button ("Restart")) 
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("LEVEL 1");
    }
    if (GUILayout.Button("Quit"))
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("Main Menu");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you've posted the same question 3 times and in fact on a previous post you already have an accepted answer :) You might get more/quicker help on the unity forums.

Comment: I know but you gave me a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
IEnumerator StopBall(float delay)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    // Stop the ball code
}
```

Call it like this:

```
StopBall(0.5f);
```

Where 0.5f is the amount you want to wait. Remember to add *F* to the end of the number since it's a floating point. Regards.

Comment: Please look into my project file(the link is above)and fix it because it doesnt work.I want to pause my game on a undetermined period of time

Comment: @GabiDobre I may take a look at it at some point, not downloading it to my android since it's 145MB :D

Comment: The game look like this :http://www.kongregate.com/games/GabiD25/unity-space-ball

Comment: @GabiDobre is this the answer that solved your question? I don't mean to sound as I am asking for reputation, but for the sake of users that will search try to solve the same problem in the future, the correct answer should be marked as "Accepted" - that's how StackOverflow works best. If this is truly the correct answer, I apologize.

Comment: @Arx +1 I think you're absolutely right. Your answer should be marked as accepted even tho my answer is in a way correct. I've got a feeling that he created an account just to get the answer to that one question. Hopefully he'll read this and give you your reputation :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Time.timeScale](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html) to pause/unpause the game (i.e. stop the ball from moving), like this:

```
Time.timeScale = 0f; // paused
Time.timeScale = 1f; // unpaused
```

Bear in mind that `Time.deltaTime` will then be 0 when `Time.timeScale` is 0, so you might want to use `Time.unscaledDeltaTime` in some cases.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please select it as an "accepted answer" if it helped.